# Control jQuery asynchronous ajax calls number?

Tags: jquery

How can I control how many asynchronous ajax calls are allowed?
let's say, if I set this limit to 3, the 4th request will be queued untill one of the 3 have finished.

Note: code that perform ajax calls are inserted dynamically into my page, I have no control on which function will make a request..

Comment: PS: This is very inspired by softwares that let you set how many concurrent threads you can run

Comment: You should be able to just make a wrapper on the standard `$.ajax` function that would queue up requests until previous ones returned or timed out.

Comment: you're right! I was wondering if there is a faster solution before I get into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this. I don't have a site handy to test with, sorry.

```
$.queueAjax = (function() {

  var queue = [];
  var maxConnections = 4;
  var running = 0;

  function flush() {
    while (running < maxConnections && queue.length) {
      running += 1;
      var args = queue.shift();
      var xhr = $.ajax.apply($, args);
      xhr.done(function() {
        running -= 1;
        flush();
      });
    }
  }

  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments);
    queue.push(args);
    flush();
  }
})();
```

You'd call it just like you do `$.ajax` but it will buffer requests and only allow 4 to be running at once.

If you don't want to use a separate function, you could also replace the main jQuery function, but that is pretty ugly. Something like this:

```
$.ajax = (function() {
  var ajax = $.ajax;

  var queue = [];
  var maxConnections = 4;
  var running = 0;

  function flush() {
    while (running < maxConnections && queue.length) {
      running += 1;
      var args = queue.shift();
      var xhr = ajax.apply($, args);
      xhr.done(function() {
        running -= 1;
        flush();
      });
    }
  }

  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments);
    queue.push(args);
    flush();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Actually, I can't use this because the app is full of ajax requests (some other plugins, some code from other developers, some code I've written before...)

Comment: nice, but pretty ugly :) I will just override the $.ajax in the proper way

Comment: @skafandri What do you mean "proper way"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you can't use any plugins, this is something I could think of , but not guarantees on efficiency.

var ajax_calls = new Array(); //global variable

```
if( ajax_calls.length < 3 ){
    ajax_calls.push( 
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "target.php",
            type: "POST", //or GET
            data: {varname: "value"}
            }) 
        );
}
```

And then later, you can delete the corresponding ajax controllers on success.